# Using SocketIO in external lib for expressjs

Tags: javascript, express, socket.io

my `app.js` is started with following code

```
var express = require("express"),
app     = express(),
http    = require('http'),
server  = http.createServer(app),
io      = require('socket.io').listen(server),
games   = require("./lib/games");
```

Now I need to use `socket.io` in external lib which named games,how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  One way is to have games export a function which accepts the socket.io object as a parameter.

For example:

```
// games.js
module.exports = function(io) { ... /* do something with io */ }

// app.js
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
games   = require("./lib/games");
games(io);
```